# Expose function to Javascript from a .ocx ActiveX

Tags: delphi, activex, ole, ocx

I have developed an `.ocx` using Delphi.
Rad Studio auto generated a `.ridl` file for me.

I have created an html page that loads the `.ocx activeX`, and it works without any problem.

Now, i need to call a function inside the `.ocx` file from Javascript inside the Html page, i know that its possible but i cannot figure how. I think i have to somehow configure the `.ridl` file but i cannot find any documentation about it.

Right now, i declared a public function inside the form i created, like this:

```
procedure WriteText(const text: string); safecall;
```

and, from Javascript, i call it like this:

```
document.forms[0].MyProjectName.WriteText('foo');
```

but i got the error `variable type invalid` (i somewhat suspect its a **EOleSysError** type error). So i can see the WriteText function but i cannot use it.

I also tried replacing `string` type in my function with `WideString` and `PWideChar`, with always the same error.

How i can solve this?

Comment: Keep in mind that Microsoft dropped support for ActiveX in web pages many, many years ago. Only worked in IE, and they didn't even carry it over to Edge.

Comment: A time traveller from the late 20th Century! Welcome!

Comment: ahahah well, i understand its a deprecated tecnology but.. i have to deal with it!

Comment: FWIW, a few years ago I experimented with writing gadgets for the Windows 7 desktop using Delphi. It's essentially an HTML document which I can embed an ActiveX control which I built in Delphi. It was sloppy, but it worked. Just last week, I tried to use those gadgets and they no longer work. I also don't care to pick the project back up because I know it won't be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by giving the an ID to the `<OBJECT>` element, and calling the method via javascript like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
  someID.WriteText('Hello!');
</script>
```

And somewhere in the page:

```
<OBJECT ID="someID"
        CLASSID="clsid:12345678-90AB-CDEF-1234-56789ABCDEF1"
        CODEBASE="/my.ocx"
        WIDTH="100"
        HEIGHT="25">
```